# What Next? What do I do at the GRUB prompt? WUBI Install

Tags: grub2, wubi

So I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and did the reboot as instructed.

When I select Ubuntu at the boot menu it takes me to a command line prompt

`GRUB>`

IS that where I am supposed to be?  should of it gone to the Desktop GUI?

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Did you try a sime `help` command?

Comment: Did you ever have the Wubi install booting, or did it go to the grub prompt the first time?

Answer (score 0):

This means that something went really wrong on installing your system. :( What you see is the `GRUB rescue`.

First of all try to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If does not boot, then enter the following commands (every line is followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
insmod (hd0,2)/boot/grub/linux.mod
set prefix=(hd0,2)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,2)
insmod (hd0,2)/boot/grub/linux.mod
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2 ro
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

After a successful boot, open a Terminal and type:

`sudo update-grub`

and let's hope the best.

**NOTE**
It seems that you are a beginner, so I advice you to search an expert to help you.

Comment: Thanky you i will give ot a shot! Yes i am a beginner with Ubuntu but i want to learn .

Comment: So when i enter the commands it came back as invalid file name

Comment: On which command?

Comment: Why `/dev/sda2`? It's not clear from the question that this partition is relevant. And it's a wubi install so it needs to loopmount the root.disk. Those commands won't work.